# How to unwrap a ring to straight gird?

Tags: uv

I want my texture to circle around the top of the ring.

Any solution to unwrap the ring to straight grid?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a perfectly straight strip, select 2 points on one side of a section of your unwrapped ring (preferably one that already has 2 "flat" edges - such as the one at the top). Set your transform pivot point to "Active element".

[image: Unwrap1]

Scale the 2 points to 0 on whatever axis you are using (I used X) to make the points straight in line on this axis. Do this on both sides until you have a rectangle.

[image: Unwrap2]

Now select the whole thing, keeping the "rectangle" selected. Press U for unwrap in the 3D viewport and select "follow active quads". This will make your selection into a strip.

[image: Unwrap3]

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Big thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it before the unwrap:

Select the ring of your object, then select one of its face to make it active, and unwrap with the *Follow Active Quads* option (you may need to unwrap > *Reset* before):

[image]

If you've already unwrapped you can still make your ring a straight line in the *UV Editor* with the help of the *UV Squares* addon (which must be in Blender by default): Select the ring, press <kbd>T</kbd> to display the tools, and in the bottom you should see all the addon's tools. Press on the *To Square Grid* button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help